# ValueError that should be caught and skipped, yet crashes program

Tags: python, pandas, string

What is the issue with:

```
            try:
                number = int((self.final_df_1[index1_name][i])[:first_space_a])
            except TypeError or ValueError:
                continue
```

For some background, that entry in the `Dataframe` is a string of an address. The argument of `int()` is simply the first "word," which in this case is the street number. The logic here is that I want to try to convert that street number into an integer, and if it happens to throw TypeError or ValueError, I want to skip to the next iteration of the `for` loop that this is nested within, ie, to the next row of the Dataframe. This is practical because the CSV's I'm parsing through contain thousands of addresses, and occasionally one will be formatted oddly (such as '74271/2,' which is one of the few entries that consistently throws this error in the test set).

I would expect this chunk of code to, during the attempt to convert to an integer, catch the error and, again, skip to the next iteration of the loop, but instead it does anything but what it's supposed to do.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how is it crashing and what error are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try doing

```
            try:
                number = int((self.final_df_1[index1_name][i])[:first_space_a])
            except (TypeError,ValueError):
                continue
```

instead of

```
            try:
                number = int((self.final_df_1[index1_name][i])[:first_space_a])
            except TypeError or ValueError:
                continue
```

This will check for both errors and the program won't crash. You can extend this to any amount of errors you want to check for.

Comment: That did it. Thank you.

For the sake of edification, what's the difference between ```or``` and this? Seems like they should be equivalent

Comment: if you do `except TypeError or ValueError`, Python tries to figure out what is `TypeError or ValueError` and check for that error. For some reason, only the first error is checked. If you do `except (TypeError,ValueError)`, it checks for all errors in the tuple `(TypeError,ValueError)`